# Automatic onepage checkout Magento - Shipping method

Tags: php, magento, checkout

I'm working on the automation of the shipping method, it seems to be working fine, but problem is:

Every 2nd order there is same error "Please specify a shipping method"

Can it be session error? Should variables be send over get-post or retrieved from Magento in other way?

Here is a code:

```
<?php
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();


$customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());

echo $customAddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($customer->getDefaultBilling());


$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->setBillingAddress(Mage::getSingleton('sales/quote_address')->importCustomerAddress($customAddress));

$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');

$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();

$checkout = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage');

$checkout->initCheckout();

$checkout->saveCheckoutMethod('register');

$checkout->saveShippingMethod('matrixrate_matrixrate_35');

$checkout->savePayment(array('method'=>'pay'));

Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setShippingMethod('matrixrate_matrixrate_35');


try {
    if ($checkout->saveOrder()) {echo "SUCCESSSSS!!!";}}
catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}            

/* Clear the cart */
$cart->truncate();
$cart->save();
$cart->getItems()->clear()->save();
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->clear();
```

It's using custom payment gateway called Pay and I'm using matrixrate extension for shipping, althought there is same eror on flatrate_flatrate so I don'd consider it as extension issue.

Thanks!!!

Adam

Comment: UPDATE: clearing the cart after order was messing it up, I'm solving now shipment price issue. I've also added code on cart page to set shipping method.

Comment: I'm also suggest you avoid to use var_dumps or echos, because sometimes this prints sent you "alerts" errors like the one you mention before.

Comment: Thanks Beto, I'll get rid of them.

UPDATE: I've managed to get the cart going, but first order when user log in doesn't process as it tells that there is no shipping method, second and rest works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Issue: Cart items still displaying after order splitting

1.Save quote collection in shipping method step..

```
$quote->collectTotals()->save();
```

2.Add the below steps in the last section of the order split.

```
$quote->setIsActive(false);
$quote->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM IS SOLVED.**

Looks like there has been issue with sessions/time, server didn't process everything at once.

I had to add on cart-total page:

```
$checkout->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setShippingMethod('matrixrate_matrixrate_35');
$checkout->saveShippingMethod('matrixrate_matrixrate_35');
```

To make sure that shipping is set, also:

session is cleared at success page manually.

There has been a bug with total quote amount, so I just redesigned script to count it properly.

Many Thanks for help!!

Adam